# Can I install a better RAMs?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building

Well I got a free PC it's old tbh but I was interested in the clock speed, so I checked the RAMs, and they are total at 1 GB of RAM. So I was wondering if I can increase over 4 GB (8 GB would be enough for me) and which model is recommended?

That's the motherboard I have:
[link to Asus P5S800VM motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P5S800VM/overview/)

Comment: @n8te so that's almost dead old, and probably won't find a match right?

Comment: No; 4GB is the maximum amount of memory supported by your motherboard

Comment: DDR1 is expensive these days, you could buy an entire 2nd hand computer for the same price, one that would take 8GB DDR2

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer states

Memory
2 x DIMM, Max. 2 GB, DDR SDRAM ,Non-ECC, Memory

> Maximum 2GB

Comment: Also, in case OP is wondering: No, you can’t install DDR2 or DDR3 or whatever. It has to be DDR “1”.

Comment: @Seth: the statement from the manufacturer site clearly states that 2x Dimm slots and maximum amount of total memory is 2GB.

Comment: @Seth: one more thing, back than maximum **DDR 400 DIMM Size was 1GB**. and there is no such thing as **2GB DDR 400 DIMM**.